# Who was the first christian?

Tags: church-history

Jesus is said to have been born a Jew, and the same goes for his followers. So then who was the first christian?

Comment: Welcome to the site M.A.J. This question needs more details in order to remain on topic. Could you please [edit](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/78285/who-was-the-first-christian) in some more information and parameters into your subject matter.

Comment: You will need to establish a definition of what a Christian is for the purpose of your question.

Comment: The earliest reference I can find to _meshiach_ ['messiah', anointed, 'christ'] is Exodus 40:15 _... their anointing (the sons of Aaron) shall surely be an everlasting priesthood throughout their generations_.

Comment: In Jewish eschatology, the term messiah refers to a future Jewish king from the Davidic line, who will be "anointed" with holy anointing oil, to be king of God's kingdom, and rule the Jewish people during the Messianic Age. In Judaism, a messiah is not considered to be God or a pre-existent divine Son of God.

Comment: Believers in Jesus were first called 'Christians' at Antioch (in Syria) see Acts 20:26.

Comment: @Codosaur That is not the first usage (and therefore the etymological definition) of the word _meshiach_.

Comment: If defined as the first human to believe jesus is the Christ/messiah. Then I would say Mary is first christian

Comment: @NigelJ, the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messiah_in_Judaism#Etymology) is from Biblical Hebrew מָשִׁיחַ‎. *māšîaḥ* so its origin is clearly Judaic, and it did not have the exclusive connotation Christians assign to it.

Comment: It's important to realize that in the early church you could be both a Jew and a Christian.

Comment: do many Christian "Messianic Jews," and even other Christians, do, or try to do, that today?